# What are the eight fold paths in the Gita?

Tags: krishna, gita

> BG 4.28:Some offer their wealth as sacrifice, while others offer severe austerities as sacrifice. **Some practice the eight-fold path of yogic practices**, and yet others study the scriptures and cultivate knowledge as sacrifice, while observing strict vows.

So what are the eight fold paths in the Gita?

*The Eightfold Path consists of eight practices: right view, right resolve, right speech, right conduct, right livelihood, right effort, right mindfulness, and right samadhi ('meditative absorption or union')*.

These are the eight fold paths according to Buddhism.

Are the eight fold paths mentioned in the Gita different or are they same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Eight fold paths" are not explicitly mentioned in this verse of Gita. The term which is mentioned is "Yoga Yajna"

> द्रव्ययज्ञास्तपोयज्ञा **योगयज्ञा**स्तथापरे।
> स्वाध्यायज्ञानयज्ञाश्च यतयः संशितव्रताः।।4.28।।
>
> dravya-yajñās tapo-yajñā **yoga-yajñā**s tathāpare
> swādhyāya-jñāna-yajñāśh cha yatayaḥ sanśhita-vratāḥ

- According to Adi Shankaracharya, "योगयज्ञाः प्राणायामप्रत्याहारादिलक्षणो योगो यज्ञो येषां ते योगयज्ञाः।" means Yoga in which Pranayama, Pratyahara etc. are involved is Yoga Yajna.
- **The translation provided in the questionbody is by Swami Muktananda, the [commentary by him](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4/verse/28) clearly takes Patanjali's Ashtanga Yoga as the Yoga Yagna.**
- [Commentary by Swami Sivananda](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=28&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1) also says the same.

So, to conclude, Though the eight fold paths are not explicitly mentioned in the Geeta but the term "Yoga Yajna" refers to Asthanga Yoga of Patanjali according to Acharyas. Eight limbs of that are Yama, Niyama, Asana, Pranayama, Pratyahara, Dharana, Dhayana and Samadhi.

Answer (score 2):

This is neither eightfold path nor Aṣṭānga Yoga of patanjali, It's rather completely directing your energies to live in the present according to Ācārya Abhinavgupta as evident from his commentary on the same verse,

> Some others surrender all actions of their sense organs, the mind as well as the activity of prana consisting of the expiration of air through mouth and nose as well as that air which causes urine to move downwards. (They surrender all these activities) into the fire of one-pointedness, which is called yoga and which is instrumental in controlling the mind. This fire of one-pointedness, which is insatiated, **is lit by right knowledge**. The purport is that they grasp objects either (really) enjoyed or imagined by the one-pointed mind, while at the same time they turn away from all other objects. 
> It is said in Vijnanabhairava:
>
> > When the mind of a yogin abandons one object, which (mind) because of
> > being under control does not move to another object, then, by resting
> > in the gap between two thoughts the realization of pure consciousness
> > unfolds.33 (Vijnanabhairava, 62)

It's also easier to practice. If you could direct whole of the energies to live in a present moment, then whatever is being said by Ācārya can be tested by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer